# Flatten nested json and get keys and nested keys in python

Tags: python, json

I need to extract keys and nested keys from json. Here's my example text:

```
{"Field1":"a","Field2":"b","Field3":"c","AdditionalInfo":{"Name":"foo"}}
```

The following code adds nested keys as both nested keys and regular keys:
`(AdditionalInfo_Name,Field1,Field2,Field3,Name)`

```
fields = []

def flatten_dict(d):
    def items():
        for key, value in d.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                for subkey, subvalue in flatten_dict(value).items():
                    yield key + "." + subkey, subvalue
                    if (key + "." + subkey) not in fields:
                        fields.append(key + "." + subkey)
            else:
                yield key, value
                if key not in fields:
                    fields.append(key)

    return dict(items())
```

How do I revise this function so I get this instead? You'll note that I don't want the last key, Name, since it doesn't exist in my sample text:
`(AdditionalInfo_Name,Field1,Field2,Field3)`

Comment: Can you please share how your actual dictionary should look?

Comment: I'm using this to create a list of fields. I'll update the code to make that clear. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not entirely clear what you are after, but using `flatten_json` library will give you the flattened dictionary, and the keys pretty easily.

```
from flatten_json import flatten
data = {"Field1":"a","Field2":"b","Field3":"c","AdditionalInfo":{"Name":"foo"}}
flattened_dict = [flatten(d, '.') for d in [data]][0]
flattened_keys = [flatten(d, '.') for d in [data]][0].keys()


In [31]: flattened_dict
Out[31]: {'Field1': 'a', 'Field2': 'b', 'Field3': 'c', 'AdditionalInfo.Name': 'foo'}

In [32]: flattened_keys
Out[32]: dict_keys(['Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3', 'AdditionalInfo.Name'])
```

Comment: Yep, that's exactly what I needed. Thank you!